# How to measure accuracy of GPT model

Tags: accuracy, gpt, llm, chatgpt

I am working on a model to build questions automatically from some text

My model will analyse provided article and ask authors questions that can help improving their articles

How can we measure the accuracy of these ML-generated questions?

There is the relevance part of the questions as these questions represent an area of improvement in the article

How to measure that?

Any previous work on similar models would be a great help too

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Question Generation section](https://paperswithcode.com/task/question-generation) of [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/). There, you can see for different datasets how the performance is measured and how different proposed approaches compare on them.

Usually, you check how similar is the question to the reference text.  Some used measures are BLEU-1 (based on matching unigrams) and ROUGE-L (based on the longest common subsequence). This is "unsupervised testing" in the sense that you don't need labeled data. However, they may not be directly correlated with their actual quality (see [*Towards a
better metric for evaluating question generation systems*](https://aclanthology.org/D18-1429/) and [*Addressing Semantic Drift in Question Generation for Semi-Supervised Question Answering*](https://aclanthology.org/D19-1253/)).

In other cases, they use [QA-based Evaluation (QAE)](https://aclanthology.org/D19-1253), which measures how
similar the generated QA pairs are compared to some ground truth QA pairs. For this, you need a reference labeled QA dataset on which the model is to be evaluated.

Comment: If you find the answers useful, please consider upvoting it and accepting it if you consider it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks, but these measures focus on the "Answerability" of the questions.. What I am looking for is to measure the "Relativity" of the question;  as is this the right question to ask?

Comment: QAE focuses on answerability, but the others (BLEU, ROUGE) do not; you can check [_Towards a Better Metric for Evaluating Question Generation Systems_](https://aclanthology.org/D18-1429/)) regarding this. How do you define "relativity"? Are you referring to how related those questions are to the reference text?

Comment: yes i meant how relavent those questions are to the reference text